# Change the order of array according to multiple values is associative array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

after sorting array using this function

```
$keys = array_column($matchUser, 'score');
array_multisort($keys, SORT_DESC , $matchUser);
```

i got below sorting order now i want to make another sorting order if score is duplicate the rating should be high. so basically if score is matched then decision should be from rating as per array 9.5 score is 3 time then order should be change according to skill_rating 4.8 is higher in 9.5 score

```
array:15 [▼
  0 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 156
    "skills_rating" => 4.7
    "score" => 9.5
  ]
  1 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 170
    "skills_rating" => 4.7
    "score" => 9.5
  ]
  2 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 188
    "skills_rating" => 4.8
    "score" => 9.5
  ]
  3 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 153
    "skills_rating" => 4.7
    "score" => 9.2
  ]
  4 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 154
    "skills_rating" => 4.4
    "score" => 9.2
  ]
  5 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 169
    "skills_rating" => 4.5
    "score" => 9.2
  ]
  6 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 171
    "skills_rating" => 4.7
    
    "score" => 9.0
  ]
  7 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 157
    "skills_rating" => 4.4
    "score" => 8.9
  ]
  8 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 168
    "skills_rating" => 4.4
    "score" => 8.9
  ]
  9 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 186
    "skills_rating" => 4.4
    "score" => 8.9
  ]
  10 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 172
    "skills_rating" => 4.6

    "score" => 8.8
  ]
  11 => array:6 [▼
    "user" => 187
    "skills_rating" => 4.5
    "score" => 8.8
  ]

]
```

Comment: Please reformat the array in your post. This is unreadable

Comment: please review now

Comment: @Baracuda078 this is the right format

Comment: This looks more like a database table not an array. where do you get your data from

Comment: @Baracuda078 updated